# 1980s book about global warming

Tags: story-identification

I read a book in the 1980s that involved global warming. I remember very little of the story. It described mega-storms and there is a long stretch when a group of people are in a large RV getting to higher ground to escape flooding.

The hero is a scientist and he was in the RV. It could be from the early 90s but I remember it was the first book I came across that dealt with global warming.

It is not a series.

Before posting here I searched for global warming science fiction and read summaries of the books I found. It is not by Kim Stanley Robinson or Margaret Atwood.

It is none of these:

- The Bone Clocks by David Mitchell
- The Drowned World by J.G. Ballard
- Heavy Weather by Bruce Sterling
- Mother of Storms by John Barnes Odds
- Against Tomorrow by Nathaniel Rich
- The Sea and The Summer by George Turner
- Surviving Abe by J.Z. O'Brien
- The Windup Girl by Paolo Bacigalupi

Comment: Interesting, however this global warming floods + escaping to higher ground trope is a common one, could you add any more details at all? Check out [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/21267) to see if it helps jog your memory.

Comment: Are you sure the novel was from the 1980s?  The reason I ask is that there is an SF novel called Mother of Storms by John Barnes which matches pretty well to what you are describing. Including a scene in which people are in an RV trying to get to higher ground and mega-storms.  The only thing is that it is from 1994.  As Mooz indicates, however, this is a common trope so could easily be a different novel.  But link is here if this rings any bells or cover art might be familiar:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_of_Storms

Comment: @beichst thanks but not it. edited question with more info.

Comment: Try [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Environmental_fiction_books) and see if any ring a bell.

Comment: thanks Tim but none of them are it.

Comment: There was a Piers Anthony book called (I think) The Rings of Sharon that had a plot like that also

Comment: The Piers Anthony book is called "Rings of Ice" and does involve people in an RV escaping global flooding. The flooding is caused by rains caused by a comet, not global warming, but otherwise it is close.

Comment: "rings of ice" is indeed one of the stories i conflated. i couldn't find it at any of the local libraries but it can be borrowed from archive.org. i've read enough to confirm it is the winnebago story. the scientist is a woman--i had that wrong. the mega storm story will have to stay lost in time. i don't remember anything more than they were mentioned at the beginning of the book. i don't think the characters live through any storm.

Comment: @tnt: You can answer your own question. In fact, we recommend it.

Comment: So are you asking two questions then? One about scientist in an RV and another about a mega storm?

Comment: @Danny3414 yes. Heat by Arthur Herzog could be the other, scientist/storm, book. it sounds pretty close but i'll have to get a copy to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Rings of Ice" by Piers Anthony, 1974, is indeed one of the stories I conflated. I couldn't find it at any of the local libraries but it can be borrowed from archive.org. I've read enough to confirm it is the Winnebago story. The scientist is a woman -- I had that wrong.  [@Jacob C is correct, the mega-storms story is "Heat" by Arthur Herzog.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/170037/31936) I received a copy today and confirmed.

Answer (score 5):

Could it be Heat by Arthur Herzog? That was the first SF story I ever read involving global warming. It was first published in 1977. It is [described at eco-fiction.com](https://eco-fiction.com/heat-arthur-herzog/) (inluding a quote from the author's widow mentioning the research he did for it) and [in a review at LibraryThing](http://www.librarything.com/work/910939/reviews/112108343). Excerpts from the latter:

> Somewhere in a secret underground laboratory, Lawrence Pick - an engineer who predicted and analyzed large-scale calamities that might affect the national security of the United States - gathers startling evidence that the world's weather may be rapidly changing, as a prelude to a fundamental alteration in global climate. They call him an alarmist - a gloomy, anxious pessimist. Lawrence resented the label, but for himself and a team of equally skilled scientists, the evidence is irrefutable

...

> Now, as freakish weather conditions prevail: extraordinary tornadoes and hurricanes, droughts, violent hailstorms and windstorms, as well as savage waterspouts - Lawrence's various 'over-reactive' weather predictions become a stunning reality.

Comment: as i said above, this could be the other, scientist/storm, book.

Answer (score 0):

State of Fear by Michael Crichton?

Comment: :) Please add to your answer how it answers their query.